# Bound UIView frame to Method frame inside another class

Tags: swift, uiview, frame, nsobject

Currently I have an `Method` inside a `UIView` that has been added as a subview. I would like to know how I can keep the Method's properties so its frame dictates the size of the `UIView`.

**NSObject:**

```
public class func drawCanvas1(frame frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 86, height: 31)) {

    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: frame.minX + frame.width - 86, y: frame.minY + floor((frame.height) * 0.00000 - 0.5) + 1, width: 86, height: frame.height - 1 - floor((frame.height) * 0.00000 - 0.5)))
    UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()

}
```

**UIView:**

```
class shapeTestUI: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {        
        StyleKitName.drawCanvas1()        
    }
}
```

**View Controller:**

```
var block1: shapeTestUI = shapeTestUI()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 38.0 / 255, green: 151.0 / 255, blue: 68.0 / 255, alpha: 1)

    let block = createBlock(block1)
    self.view.addSubview(block)

}

func createBlock(blocks:UIView) -> UIView {

    let block = blocks as UIView!
    //block.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)

    return block
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** your code does not show a "method" being added as a subview as this is not possible. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming).

**Second,** Overriding the `drawRect` function does not add a subview but instead draws the `UIView` itself according to the code inside it (i.e. the PaintCode StyleKit function).

**Third,** If you want the frame of the UIView to be dictated by the drawing code alter your PaintCode function like so:

```
public class func drawCanvas1(frame: CGRect) {
   let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: frame.minX + frame.width - 86, y: frame.minY + floor((frame.height) * 0.00000 - 0.5) + 1, width: 86, height: frame.height - 1 - floor((frame.height) * 0.00000 - 0.5)))
   UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
   rectanglePath.fill()
}
```

Next, in `shapesTestUI`, you should pass the parameter `rect` of `drawRect` to the modified PaintCode function:

```
class shapeTestUI: UIView {

   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {        
      StyleKitName.drawCanvas1(rect)        
   }
}
```

And last, you should give the desired CGRect when initializing `block1` in your View Controller

```
var block1: shapeTestUI = shapeTestUI(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 86, height: 31))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ike. Second or third question you have helped me with this week. Apreciate it.